# converting array to object while considering keys of the same value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to figure out an easy way to convert an array of objects to an object

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
   [
      {
       "id": "-LP9_kAbqnsQwXq0oGDT",
       "value": Object {
         "date": 1541482236000,
         "title": "First",
       },
     },
    .... more objects here
   ]
```

And id like to convert it to an object with the timestamps as the keys, and arrays of objects corresponding to that date. If that key already exists, then add the object to the corresponding array associated with that key

```
 {
   1541482236000: 
     [{
           "id": "-LP9_kAbqnsQwXq0oGDT",
           "value": Object {
             "date": 1541482236000,
             "title": "First",
           },
         },
         {
           "id": "-LP9_kAbqnsQwXqZZZZ",
           "value": Object {
             "date": 1541482236000,
             "title": "Some other title",
           },
         },
        .... more objects here
     ],
  1541482236001: 
     [{
           "id": "-LP9_kAbqnsQ1234",
           "value": Object {
             "date": 1541482236001,
             "title": "Another title",
           },
         },

        .... more objects here
     ]
 }
```

I was able to achieve something similar using reduce. However it does not handle adding objects to the array when their key already exists.

```
calendarReminders = action.value.reduce((obj, reminder) => {
                dateKey = moment(reminder.value.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                obj[dateKey] = [reminder]
                return obj;
            }, {});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It would be useful to have a fuller example of the input, so that an output (of size greater than 1) could be constructed, would you be able to post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check whether the object is already a key and if not add it with the value of an array. Then you can just `push()` into it:

```js
let arr = [{"id": "-LP9_kAbqnsQwXq0oGDT","value":  {"date": 1541482236000,"title": "First",},},{"id": "SomID","value":  {"date": 1541482236000,"title": "Some other title",},},{"id": "A different ID","value":  {"date": 1541482236001,"title": "A third title",},}]

 let calendarReminders = arr.reduce((obj, reminder) => {
    (obj[reminder.value.date] || (obj[reminder.value.date] = [])).push(reminder)
    return obj;
}, {});
console.log(calendarReminders)
```

If you want to set the keys to a different format with moment, you should be able to do that without changing the basic idea.

Comment: I couldnt get your answer working, but it put me on the basic track to solve the issue. I ended up using lodash _.has to check if the key already existed, then pushing the reminder onto the array in that case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please test the below code!

First you iterate through your array of data, 
if your result object/dictionary already has the key then you just add the current item

otherwise you make the key and set the value

```
const data = [];

let result = {};

for (const item of data) {
  const key = item.value.date;
  if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    const prevData = result[key];
    result[key] = [...prevData, item];
  } else {
    result[key] = [item];
  }
}
```